# MongoDB removes slow

Tags: mongodb

I've got one question.

I have a database that I've downloaded of about 1 million objects
They have a key that is countries_tags which is an array that contains values like en:spain

that key is indexed and if I count how many have it, it's 161,000

I used this query to delete all the ones that don't have en:spain
db.products.remove({countries_tags: {$not: /en:spain/}})

but it takes like three hours because it erases so slowly, some way to speed it up?

This is the way that the countries are stored inside the object

```
    ...
    "countries_tags" : [
       "en:spain",
       "en:uk"
]
```

Comment: so you have an array like `["en:spain", "en:de", ...]` and so on?

Comment: @Ifaruki yes, exactly. I'll update the answer clarifying that.